# Setting upper limit on user profile picture

Tags: 7, users

I am not finding any option to set upper limit on user profile picture. Currently user can upload file of any size. I want to prevent this scenario and allow user to upload his picture of maximum 2Mb  or other.

How can set upper limit on profile picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find it here: admin/config/people/accounts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yoursite.com/admin/config/people/accounts

it's set here, where you enable user pictures.  don't forget to change your PHP file size limits to match.